# IE7 CSS/Js Bugs

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm helping a friend do a little jquery, and along with that is some simple CSS work...but I'm no CSS expert, and things (as usual) are acting a fool in IE7--I think they are fine in IE8, but the client needs it to work in IE7...ahem.

**I forgot to mention specific problems**:

1. The Main nav contains a drop-down.  In IE7 it doesn't work.
2. The content/pic scroller acts a bit funny--there is a border around the first image (that should stay as a background image).  In IE7, it scrolls with the first image.

Can you *please* help me by showing my error!?  I'm not sure what the problem is, but I'm almost sure it's CSS related...

Suggestions and ideas are most welcome!  Thanks for your time!  I know IE is a pain sometimes!  :)

Here's the dev site [link](http://ftp.crashboxcreative.com/ftp/EastsideBaptist/devSite/).

Comment: you were so focused on cursing IE7 that you've forgotten to post your code examples.

Comment: The link to the site is there now...sorry.

Comment: Maybe expand a little on "acting a fool" - some screenies or a description of what's going wrong might help :-)

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? At least I'm not willing to fire up IE7 just to see what *might* be wrong on that page.

Comment: it would really help if you let us know exactly what problems you are experiencing in ie 7

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  It looks fine to me in IE7 on a virtual XP SP3 machine.

Comment: Again, I apologize.  :(  Details added.

Comment: In addition to the problems you've listed, IE8 with compatibility mode enabled also has problems with the alignment of the "Service Times" section at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to your style.css:

```
li.drop-down > A {
    text-indent: -4000px;
    width: 4000px;
}
```

IE 7 is not triggering mouseenter event probably because it cannot see the element with such a large indent. Adding width makes it more visible to the browser at least.

**Edit:** Alternatively you could trigger the mouseenter on the li itself, rather than the anchor.

```
$("li.drop-down").bind("mouseenter",function(){
  var _li=$(this);
  $(".subMenu").slideUp("fast");
  $("."+_li.attr("id")).stop(true, true).slideDown("fast");
});
```

As for the background border issue, try wrapping your UL of images in a plain DIV.

```
<div>
  <ul style="width: 3100px; margin-left: -384.733px;"><li style="margin-left: -620px; float: left;"><img src="Eastside%20Baptist%20Home%20Page_files/jQueryPlaceHolder4.jpg" alt="Fourth Picture"></li>
    <li style="float: left;"><img src="Eastside%20Baptist%20Home%20Page_files/jQueryPlaceHolder.jpg" alt="jQueryPlaceHolder"></li>
    <li style="float: left;"><img src="Eastside%20Baptist%20Home%20Page_files/jQueryPlaceHolder2.jpg" alt="Second Picture"></li>
    <li style="float: left;"><img src="Eastside%20Baptist%20Home%20Page_files/jQueryPlaceHolder3.jpg" alt="Third Picture"></li>
    <li style="float: left;"><img src="Eastside%20Baptist%20Home%20Page_files/jQueryPlaceHolder4.jpg" alt="Fourth Picture"></li>
    <li style="float: left;"><img src="Eastside%20Baptist%20Home%20Page_files/jQueryPlaceHolder.jpg" alt="jQueryPlaceHolder"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked for the slider!  Good job there!  However, the drop-down didn't change at all...  Any reason you use a capital "A"?

Comment: Hmmm, the drop downs work in IE7 on my computer with that added CSS. Shouldn't matter if it's an upper or lowercase A. Did you clear your cache after changing it?

Comment: Yea, it's not working... (Sorry it took me so long to respond!)

Comment: Ah, I think it works in IE 7!  IE 6 doesn't support child selectors?

Comment: Check out the alternative hack I've added to the answer. Actually the child selector doesn't have to even be there, you could do 'li.drop-down a'. IE has supported child selectors since 5.5. I don't have IE6 installed, so can't really test it.

Comment: Yea, that works to fix the drop-down...but it screws up the layout.

I think I'm going to drop support for IE7!